# Windows 8.1 a lot of programs stopped responding

Tags: windows-8, video, skype, vlc-media-player

I am using windows 8.1, and I cant play any video's?
I have tried opening the video with:
Windows media player, standard windows video app(in windows 8), and VLC player.
Also, when I am starting amd control center, I will get a message amd stopped responding.
Could it be something with directx, since that was the last thing i installed?
I got error's when starting games like:
"directx encountered an unrecoverable error" 
Thats why I re installed directx(before that everything worked fine)
I have tried downloading the newest directx, but it wont install since there is a newer version available on my computer.
Also, my steam and skype will get a "stopped responding" message
What should I do?

Comment: *"I will get a message amd stopped responding."* **What** stopped responding? Perhaps you mean `Display driver AMD has stopped responding`? Can you give us more information about your system? Is this a laptop or desktop? What model GPU are you using? Have you updated your drivers recently?

Comment: Well, when starting for example vlc player, i will get a message (instantly) saying "vlc media player has stopped working". I have got a Dell laptop, 17R 5721, and i believe i updated drivers from intel display driver i believe?

Comment: If you upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8.0 you need to install display drivers supported by Windows 8.1.  The drivers you had installed are not supported.  Actual DirectX supoprt is actually handled by your display drivers.

Comment: I did install all drivers, what driver do you suggest me to install/re install?

Answer (score 0):

[Your laptop](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-17r-5721_Reference%20Guide2_en-us.pdf) has both integrated and discrete graphics. Upon upgrading to Windows 8.1, you need to update the *AMD* graphics driver, not the *Intel* one. This is entirely dependent on which of the two available GPUs you have. The latest 7670m driver can be found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/22/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-17r-5721?driverId=6097M&osCode=W864&fileId=3159568692&languageCode=en&categoryId=VI). The latest 8730m driver can be found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/22/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-17r-5721?driverId=VHY54&osCode=W864&fileId=3126513687&languageCode=en&categoryId=VI)

Comment: I know, i have had a lot of trouble with that, but i got it all working, but i checked with a program called "driverscanner" and they said i was missing "intel display driver"(i believe it was called that), so i installed and now (almost) nothing works, everything just stops working

Comment: @GuusvanWalstijn Try disabling the integrated graphics from the bios if possible.

Comment: I have already bin in my bios searching for that, but it aint there

Comment: @GuusvanWalstijn Have you tried disabling it in the device manager then?

Comment: Yes, but that also wont work

Comment: Well, it does work(disbale hd 4000), but will this mean i am using my HD 8730? because dxdiag says i have Microsoft Basic Display Driver